# Ajax call do not work with multiple div using each function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two `div` with same data-domain attribute but when I use AJAX within each function then only one get its data returned but not second one. This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpa6on0d/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div data-domain='mybloggertricks.com'></div>
<div data-domain='mybloggertricks.com'></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('div').each(function(){
  var element=$(this);
  var domainname=element.attr('data-domain')
  $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', url:"http://www."+domainname+"/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&callback=simple",
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'simple',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
          element.append(json.feed.title.$t)
        }
});
});
```

Comment: Works sometimes in [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/tesiq/1/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the JS code is trying to run the non-existent function "simple". Since it does not exist the JS breaks and does not run the ajax for the second time. If you remove the callback the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f36gv8am/) works perfectly:

**HTML**

```
<div data-domain='mybloggertricks.com'></div>
<div data-domain='mybloggertricks.com'></div>
```

**Javascipt**

```
$('div').each(function(){
  var element=$(this);
  var domainname=element.attr('data-domain')
  $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url:"http://www."+domainname+"/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
          element.append(json.feed.title.$t)
        }
});
});
```

You can do it like that or add the callback and everything should be fine.

Comment: Works perfectly, looking for something like this one.